# grep --exclude does not exclude my file

Tags: grep, search

I am searching a dir for a particular string (to see all instances of where the string is present and in which files). However, I want to exclude one particular file from being searched.

Here's what is happening-

```
$echo "searchstring" > ./old_folder/useless_file
$echo "searchstring" > ./new_folder/good_file
$grep -r --exclude="old_folder/useless_file" searchstring *
./old_folder/useless_file:searchstring
./new_folder/good_file:searchstring
```

Here is the output I want-

```
./new_folder/good_file:searchstring
```

Comment: If you change `--exclude="old_folder/useless_file"` to simply `--exclude=useless_file` do you get the same problem?  (My reading of the man page suggests the pattern to `--exclude` should be the basename only, not including the path.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `--exclude` option takes globs that are matched against file names, not directories or full paths:

```
  --exclude=GLOB
          Skip   files  whose  base  name  matches  GLOB  (using  wildcard
          matching).  A file-name  glob  can  use  *,  ?,  and  [...]   as
          wildcards,  and  \  to  quote  a wildcard or backslash character
          literally.
```

So, you could do:

```
$ grep -r --exclude="*useless_file*" searchstring 
new_folder/good_file:searchstring
```

Or, to exclude all files in that directory:

```
$ grep -r --exclude-dir="old_folder" searchstring 
new_folder/good_file:searchstring
```