# Have custom grep exclude dirs for each project

Tags: grep, git

I'm curious if anyone has a way to automatically generate a different set of `--exclude-dir` flags for `grep` for each different codebase that you work in.

Because in one project, I'll never want to search in the `output/` dir, and in another, I'll never want to search in the `checkpoints/` directory.
Since there are often a few folders in a codebase that have non-source code, I always have to type those out manually (e.g. `grep --exclude_dir {onedir, twodir, threedir} ...`)

Ideally, for whatever codebase I'm in, I can just have a file in it that grep can look into to see what to automatically populate the `--exclude-dir` option with whenever I call `grep` from the command line. So that I don't have to type out a long list of directory names to exclude every time, which differ based on which project I'm currently working in.

If it could just read from an existing `.gitignore` that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script works for me

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -r .grepignore ]; then
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ "$line" =~ '#' ]] || [[ "$line" =~ ^$ ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        EXCLUDE="$EXCLUDE --exclude-dir=\"$line\""
    done < .grepignore
fi

eval grep -r "$EXCLUDE" '"$@"'
```

The script checks whether a file `.grepignore` exists and is readable. If so, it constructs a string `EXCLUDE` containing `--exclude-dir="$line"`, for any line `$line` in that file (without leading and trailing whitespace), provided it is not empty or contains a `#`. The script then passes that `EXCLUDE` string to `grep` and also adds arguments you gave to the script.

In order to execute the script, save the code in a file `mygrep`, make it executable with `chmod +x /path/to/mygrep`, and call it with `/path/to/mygrep`, followed by any options you would give to `grep` and of course by the search term.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) instead of `grep`. One of the many advantages it has is that

> By default, ripgrep will respect gitignore rules and automatically skip hidden files/directories and binary files

So it will not only respect a `.gitignore` file in the current directory, but also the global `.gitignore` file used by git.

To disable all automatic filtering by default, use `rg -uuu`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `--exclude-from=FILE` flag is what you're looking for. You'll have to  create and populate manually each project-specific `FILE` with entries like :

```
onedir/*
twodir/*
```

For convenience, you can also create a shell alias so that running `grep` will automatically call the `--exclude-from=FILE` flag.

Comment: Unfortunately, this actually doesn't work since `--exclude` and `--exclude-from` both match against base file names, so they can't include directories. See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273164/grep-exclude-does-not-exclude-my-file